# Can't get the usage of PVC through kubelet metrics

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes 1.9.11 cluster on baremetal machines running Coreos 1576.5.0.

Recently I deployed a Glusterfs 4.1.7 cluster, managed by Heketi 8, and created a lot of PVCs to be used by some statfulset applications. The problem is, I can't get metrics about these PVCs through Kublet's 10250 port:

```
curl -k https://aa05:10250/metrics 2>/dev/null | grep kubelet_volume_stats | wc -l
0
```

So, how can I get these metrics?

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: this issue is still ongoing or have you found solution?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like kubelet is implementing metrics for volumes in [release-1.9.x](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.9/pkg/kubelet/metrics/metrics.go),but their naming is quite different from what you are grepping for. Try to grep for `volume_stats`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be helpful.

```
curl -s https://aa05:10250/metrics -k|grep kubelet_volume|wc -L
0
```

Comment: I want to know what's going on. Kubernetes1.9.11 should support metrics about PVC, but I don't see it, is there any configurations needed? or it just doesn't support glusterfs.